# A opção de link sumiu do painel de edição menu do wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Esta opção: https://www.codefetti.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2.3-ClickLink.png

A opção de adicionar link no menu sumiu e no lugar esta aparecendo a opção de tags, eu não entendo pois no servidor local aparece online não, são os mesmos arquivos não mudei nada nem do wordpress nem do tema, existe alguma opção para habilitar este tipo de coisa no admin?

Existe alguma função para abilitar ou desabilitar links personalisados no menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procure do lado direito superior uma aba chamada "**Opções da Tela**" ou "**Screen Options**", clique nessa aba e selecione a opção "**Links Customizados**" ou "**Custom Links**"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Po valeu mesmo, eu achei obrigado